# npm install into a new Laravel project - error messages

Tags: laravel, npm, composer-php

I am using Laracast onto an OSX system.  I use the following shell command:

```
docker-compose exec -u laradock workspace bash
```

I created a new Laravel project...

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel stocks
cd stocks
npm install
```

Now I get some error messages:

> npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.2.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none is
>   installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN
>   img-loader@3.0.1 requires a peer of imagemin@^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0 but none
>   is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN
>   optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4
>   (node_modules/fsevents): npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
>   Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted
>   {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
>
> audited 11710 packages in 10.183s found 1 high severity vulnerability 
>   run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

How can I fix them?

Comment: Its not a error. Its just some warnings. You can try `npm run dev`

Answer (score 1):

write these for install peer

```
npm install -g npm-install-peers
```